# One to One Field throwing error "This field must be unique." django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am stuck on this error when i send a post request to my django server it only seems to return

```
   "user": [
       "This field must be unique."
       ]
   }
```

and i have done a bit of debugging and found its related to the fact i am using a one to one field here is my:
models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class EventPost(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=50 )
    event_time = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '')
    event_date = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_time
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import EventPost
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator
class EventPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventPost
        fields = (
            'user',
            'event_name',
            'event_time',
            'event_date',
        )
```

and my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import EventPost
from .serializers import EventPostSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
# Create your views here.
class PostViews(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'GET':'True',
        }
        return Response(data)

    def post(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        serializer = EventPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

I am quite new to django rest framework so please excuse me. Also please tell me if you need anymore information than this.

Comment: A `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, so yes. The values in that field need to unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-to-one fields should be used when one record of a model A is related to exactly one record of model B. This field can be useful as a primary key of an object if that object extends another object in some way. Instead use **Many-to-one relationships**:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```